# Android filepath photo ends up with file:///

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to get the right filepath to an image I'm taking with the camera. I get the right filepath but it ends up with

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture.jpg`

when i want it to end up as

`storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture.jpg`
 Any clues on how ti fix this?

```
    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File pictureDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), pictureName);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(pictureDirectory));
    imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureDirectory);

    //this ends up as file:///
    filepath = imageToUploadUri.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
filepath = imageToUploadUri.getPath();
```

or

```
File f = new File(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
filepath  = f.getAbsolutePath();
```